# Use regex to find and merge words in a string Python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string, pattern-matching

I'm trying to find a way to match and merge the teams name from a string like below. I've tried few different ways with regex but was unsuccessful. few examples:

`'30 Detroit Red Wings 12 47:06 3 8 1 3 7 0.292'`

`'31 Los Angeles Kings 11 47:45 4 7 0 4 8'`

`24 Anaheim Ducks 12 47:49 7 5 0 7 14 0.583`

I want the output to look like this:

`[30, 'Detroit Red Wings', 12, 47:06, 3, 8, 1, 3, 7, 0.292]`

`[24, 'Anaheim Ducks', 12, 47:49, 7, 5, 0, 7, 14, 0.583]`

Here is what I tried with regex but with no success:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\b\w+\b')
matches = pattern.finditer(i)
```

Comment: split() would be useful

Comment: @SPYBUG96. A Split will put each word in a seperate element. Won't work. I've tried

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. Do teams have numbers in their name?

Comment: You could theoretically use the split, check if each item in the list is an integer, then merge the sections which can be converted to a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an option using `re.findall`:

```
inp = '30 Detroit Red Wings 12 47:06 3 8 1 3 7 0.292'
matches = re.findall(r'\d+:\d+|\d+(?:\.\d+)?|[A-Za-z]+(?: [A-Za-z]+)*', inp)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['30', 'Detroit Red Wings', '12', '47:06', '3', '8', '1', '3', '7', '0.292']
```

The regex pattern used matches either a time string, an integer/floating point number, or a series of letter-only words:

```
\d+:\d+                    match a time string (e.g. '47:06')
|                          or
\d+(?:\.\d+)?              match an integer/floating point number
|                          or
[A-Za-z]+(?: [A-Za-z]+)*   match a series of words (e.g. Detroit Red Wings)
```